# What is the '.tee_history' file?

Tags: command-history, readline, tee

This is a plaintext file, apparently limited to 300 lines. I use `tee` frequently on my system.

```
$ file .tee_history
.tee_history: Unicode text, UTF-8 text
```

```
$ wc -l .tee_history
300 .tee_history
```

```
$ tee --version
tee (GNU coreutils) 9.3
```

---

I have no use for the history. Can this logging be easily disabled or would periodically truncating (`> .tee_history`) or removing the file be the most sensible solutions?

Comment: Is the file in your home directory? Have you ever used the `rlwrap` utility and maybe typed in the command `rlwrap tee`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm assuming that this relates to [an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/767898/116858) given to one of your previous questions, where the following piece of code was suggested:

```bash
a() {
  rlwrap -pblue -S 'add> ' tee --output-error=warn -a -- "$@" > /dev/null
}
```

The `a` shell function declared here uses `rlwrap` (a wrapper around the Readline library) to provide a blue `add>`  prompt for the (GNU coreutil's) `tee` utility.  When `rlwrap` is used, it creates a history file similar to your shell's history file, usually named `~/.<name>_history`, where `<name>` is the executed utility's name.

You can't turn off this history functionality completely it seems, but you can either use `/dev/null` as the history file (`-H /dev/null` or `--history-filename /dev/null`) or set the history file size to negative zero (`-s -0` or `--histsize -0`).  In the latter case, the file will still be created if it does not already exist (and if it exists, it will be read), but it is treated as read-only.

So, for example,

```bash
a() {
  rlwrap -pblue -S 'add> ' -H /dev/null -s -0 tee --output-error=warn -a -- "$@" > /dev/null
}
```

Comment: Using `/dev/null` as the history file prints the error: "rlwrap: warning: Owner of /dev/null and your effective UID don't match. History will be read-only \
warnings can be silenced by the --no-warnings (-n) option". I don't know if `--no-warnings` possibly suppresses errors I may want to be aware of (the `man` page doesn't explain the flag).

Comment: I tested with a temporary file `rlwrap --history-filename /dev/null -pblue --substitute-prompt '> ' tee --output-error=warn --append /tmp/rlwrap-sample > /dev/null`

Comment: @user598527 The `--no-warnings` option is an option to `rlwrap`. You are also using `--output-error=warn`, but this is an option to `tee`, so I don't think `--no-warnings` would affect the operation of `tee` at all.

Comment: @user598527 Suck it and see. You could always use `-s 0` instead and then periodically remove the useless empty `~/.tee_history` file.  There is, as far as I can see, no way to just _turn off_ the history feature of `rlwrap`.

Comment: @user598527 Use both `--history-filename=/dev/null` and `--histsize=-0` to avoid creating a history file. (Yes, I also think it's weird that you need both.)